# Sum of a binomial sequence equation

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

Anyone know how to go about solving this? I've tried adding the individual terms with no luck, and also I don't get how the 'n' in 15Cn doesn't correspond to `(-1)^n` like in most binomial formats.

$$\sum_{n=0}^5(-1)^n\binom5nx^{5-2n}=32$$

Terribly sorry for the formatting, I'm new here and still trying to figure everything out. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be written as
$$x^{-5}\sum_{n=0}^5 \binom{5}{n}(-1)^n x^{10-2n}$$
$$x^{-5}\sum_{n=0}^5 \binom{5}{n}(-1)^n (x^2)^{5-n}$$
$$=x^{-5}(x^2-1)^5$$
$$=(\frac{x^2-1}{x})^5=32$$

which then can be easily solved.

Comment: As $x^{-5}$ can be treated as a constant within the sum, and "reverse" the binomial expansion gives the $(x^2-1)^5$.

Comment: By the way, the question didn’t specify x to be real, so $32^{\frac{1}{5})$ can be any of the fifth roots of 32 

Comment: Worked like a charm thank you

Answer (score 0):

$$32=\binom50x^{5}-\binom52x^{3} + \binom52x^{1}-\binom53x^{-1} +  \binom54x^{-3}-\binom55x^{-5} $$

Or
$$32x^5=\binom50x^{10}-\binom52x^{8} + \binom52x^{6}-\binom53x^{4} +  \binom54x^{2}-\binom55 $$

$$ 32x^5 = (x^2-1)^5\implies 2x= x^2-1 \implies x=...$$

Comment: Last line LHS should be $32x^5$.

Answer (score 0):

Factoring out the $x^5$ (because it doesn't depend on $n$) we obtain $$x^5\sum_{n=0}^5(-1)^n{5 \choose n}x^{-2n}=32.$$ Now remark that $x^{-2n}=(\tfrac{1}{x^2})^n$. So by the binomial theorem we have $$x^5(1-\tfrac{1}{x^2})^5=32.$$ Recalling that $2^5=32$ we can take the 5th root of both sides to obtain $x(1-\tfrac{1}{x^2})=2$. Finally we multiply both sides by $x$ and rearrange to obtain the equation $$x^2-2x-1=0.$$ I'll leave the rest to you.